# Jmeter slave (distributed testing): Getting GC overhead limit exceeds in slave machines

Tags: jmeter

Jmeter slave (distributed testing): Getting GC overhead limit exceeds in slave machines when users reaches 300+. I have already made changes to jmeter.sh file in 3 machines (1 master and 2 slaves) with heap size to 3GB but for some reason this values are not considered. Please guide how and where to set heap size in slave machines.

Running in non gui mode without adding any listeners or graphs.

Running command:

---

sudo docker exec -i master /bin/bash -c "/jmeter/apache-jmeter-3.1/bin/jmeter -n -t /home/xx_journey_new.jmx -Djava.rmi.server.hostname=zz.zz.zz.zz -Dclient.rmi.localport=60000 -Rxx.xx.xx.xx,yy.yy.yy.yy -j jmeter.log -l result.csv"

jmeter.sh file in slave machines:

---

```
HEAP="-Xms1024m -Xmx3072m"
```

Tried with below also:
set HEAP=-Xms4g -Xmx4g

[image]
Please guide. Attched file has full details about errors.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking into [GC overhead limit exceeded](https://plumbr.eu/outofmemoryerror/gc-overhead-limit-exceeded) article:

> *The java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: GC overhead limit exceeded* error is displayed when **your application has exhausted pretty much all the available memory and GC has repeatedly failed to clean it**.

So it indicates the problem with your test as it uses all the heap space allocated to JMeter and [Java Garbage Collector](http://www.oracle.com/webfolder/technetwork/tutorials/obe/java/gc01/index.html) cannot efficiently free up some memory to continue.

So make sure you're:

- Following [JMeter Best Practices](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/best-practices.html)
- Sticking to recommendations from the [9 Easy Solutions for a JMeter Load Test “Out of Memory” Failure](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/9-easy-solutions-jmeter-load-test-%E2%80%9Cout-memory%E2%80%9D-failure)
- Optimize your test and leave only those test elements which are absolutely required
- Assessing other Garbage Collector implementations, i.e. [CMS](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/vm/gctuning/cms.html) or [G1](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/tutorials/tutorials-1876574.html)

Answer (score 1):

- You need to monitor your slave's memory and CPU utilization as well along with application server. Check here for more details - http://www.testautomationguru.com/jmeter-server-performance-monitoring-with-collectd-influxdb-grafana/
- Regarding the heap allocation, you can set 80% of RAM to JMeter. If it still occurs, you need to reduce the load / slave. So you need more slaves to run your test.
- You could revisit your test plan. Remove any unnecessary test elements. Remove any listeners from the test plan. http://www.testautomationguru.com/jmeter-tips-tricks-for-beginners/